# JQuery animate function dont work

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the `animate` function in jQuery. I am working locally and the function won't animate my `div` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
                });

            });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>

        <div style="position:absolute"> Animate Box </div>
        <button> Start </button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/8rYya/. If your posted code isn't working for you locally, I'd check to see that jQuery is actually loading, if not try loading it from a local source.

Comment: You fixed the code after we answered...

Comment: First you ask a question and post code that isn't working, and after we answer you fix the code so it's working -> http://jsfiddle.net/6gae3/1/ ! What a load of bull, flagged!

Comment: Jony, to elaborate on adeneo's concern, please understand that the goal of this site is to create questions and answers that help many people. If you edit the question to remove the original problem, no one can benefit from the answer. Instead, consider accepting and upvoting helpful answers below. If none of the existing answers solve the problem, post your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The animation is working perfectly fine, but the element isn't moving because it has no position or starting point:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {position: relative; left:0;}
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
                });
            });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> Animate Box </div>
        <button> Start </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6gae3/)

Comment: The div has a inline style attribute... If no `top/left/right/bottom` properties are set, the browser will default to `top:0;left:0`...

Comment: But i have in div tag style position absolute

Comment: @Jasper - it has now, it didn't when I copied the code

Comment: When i put ***left:0*** animation work good. But withoiut left he dont want animate

Comment: @Jony - I do think all browsers use `left:0` as default, but it could be jQuery is returning `auto` for some strange reason, and that's why it's not working. I normally like to place elements with `left` and `top` values in the CSS, that way they will always be at the given place, regardless of what the browser might do.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `left` property to have any effect, you must change the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property of your div. You may for example use `fixed`.

Comment: It is already set to `position:absolute` inline on the element...

Comment: @Jasper I'm sure it changed... It wasn't here initially. OP fixed the question after we answered...

Comment: No no i change grammatical errors in the words